upload blob image as word file
I'm facing an issue. I've created a page where I fetch a Word file, send its content to React-Quill for editing, and append some additional information. However, when I upload the edited React-Quill content back into a Word file, any images present in the original Word file aren't displayed. Instead, they seem to occupy space in the uploaded file. While the images appear correctly in React-Quill, they don't show up when I upload the edited content into a Word document.
const handleFileChange = async (event) => {
    try {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = async (e) => {
                const arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
                let result;
                if (file.type === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
                    result = await mammoth.convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer });
                    // Extract images and save them separately
                    const images = result.messages.filter(message => message.type === 'inline-image');
                    images.forEach((image, index) => {
                        const imageData = image.value;
                        const blob = new Blob([imageData], { type: 'image/png' }); // Adjust type as needed
                        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        saveImageToFile(blob, `image_${index}.png`);
                        // Replace image placeholders in the HTML content with appropriate <img> tags referencing the saved image files
                        result.value = result.value.replace(image.id, imageUrl);
                    });
                    setEditorHtml(result.value);
                } else if (file.type === 'application/msword') {
                    const htmlContent = convertWordToHtml(arrayBuffer);
                    setEditorHtml(htmlContent);
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Unsupported file type');
                }
            };
            if (file.type === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            } else if (file.type === 'application/msword') {
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing file:', error);
    }
};

// Function to save image file to disk
const saveImageToFile = (blob, filename) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
  const handleSave = async () => {
        try {
            // if (!inputV) {
            //     return toast.error("please provide a file name")
            // }
            const wordBlob = new Blob(['\ufeff', `<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>${editorHtml}</body></html>`], {
                type: 'application/msword',`your text``
            });
            saveAs(wordBlob, `${inputV || "file"}.doc`);
            toast.success("File saved successfully")
            setTimeout(() => {
                navigate(-1)
            }, 1000)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error converting to DOCX:', error);
        }
    }

